# How to regain access to home folder after changing group on own VM?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, system-administration

How do I regain access to my home folder?

I was trying to get shared folders to work in VirtualBox and I changed the user group to vboxsf by invoking

```
sudo usermod -a -G vboxsf dev
```

I rebooted then I lost access to /home/dev, the home user folder.

I tried to fix it but it did not work. The changes do not get persisted!!

[image]

I own the VM. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple. Just change the ownership of the folder "/home/dev"

you can do this by chown command:

```
sudo chown -R vboxsf:vboxsf /home/dev
```

and then your ownership and group will be changed from root to vboxsf

Answer (score 0):

Check if the home directory is existing by doing `ls -ltrh /home` if you see directory named `dev` then check it's owner